# How to search parenthesis by ack

Tags: shell, regular-expression, quoting, ack

I want to search for a parentheis `(` using `ack`, but neither using `(` nor `\(` worked.

The first one ("`(`") is recognized as a multiple line command.
The second one ("`\(`") is treated as an invalid regular expression.

How can I search for a parenthesis character with `ack`?

#### Error message

```
 % ack foo\(
Invalid regex 'foo(':
  Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/foo( <-- HERE / at /usr/local/bin/ack line 332.
```

Comment: Are you sure? `echo '(' | ack "\("` work fine.

Comment: @cuonglm: it works for me too

Comment: @ironsand: show exact errors you get and tell us your ack version

Comment: I added the error message. I got error message because I forget to quote the word. (My question was edited and the words are quoted.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a parenthesis character, pass backslash+parenthesis to ack.

Both backslash and parentheses are special in the shell, so you need to quote them when you're entering them in a shell script or on the command line. The simplest form of quoting is with single quotes: this tells the shell to pass everything through literally except single quotes themselves.

```
ack '\('
```

You can also use backslashes to protect special characters from shell expansion, but it tends to be less readable:

```
ack \\\(
```

The first backslash quotes the second one in the shell, so that the first character of the argument to `ack` is `\`. The third backslash quotes the parenthesis, so the second character of the argument to `ack` is `(`. Like in the case with single quotes above, the argument that `ack` sees is the two-character string `\(`.

`ack (` doesn't work because the shell sees an opening parenthesis and treats it as shell syntax. `ack \(` doesn't work because the shell passes `(` as the argument to `ack`, and ack interprets the parenthesis in the regular expression as indicating the start of a group.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the exact error you get, but here it works using escaped parenthesis ("`\(`")

```
 $ cat > test.c <<EOF
 int main() {
   return 0;
 }
 EOF
 $ ack '\(' test.c 
 int main() {
 $
```